# Hide Button After OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make the Add Custom Slug button disappear on click?

```
        <div id="myDiv" style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >

                <input type="text" name="custom_url" value="<?php echo htmlentities(@$_GET['custom_url'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>" id="custom_url" placeholder="Custom Slug" /> 

    <label for="custom_url">Optional</label> 
    </div>
<div>
<input type="button" value="Add Custom Slug" name="answer" onclick="ShowDiv()" />
</div>

    <script>
function ShowDiv() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "";
}
</script>
```

I tried many Tutorials but I couldn't

```
<input type="button" value="Add Custom Slug" name="answer" onclick="ShowDiv()" />
```

Can Anyone Help me?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";

Comment: style.display = "none"

Comment: `$('#myDiv').hide();` jquery way

Comment: display = "none";  isn't working

Comment: Updated the code but not working.

Comment: Do you want to hide `<input type="button" value="Add Custom Slug" name="answer" onclick="ShowDiv()" />  ??`

Comment: it is already hidden are you doing a hide/show for that?then you should use toggle()

Comment: I want the Button to hide when I click that..

Comment: your button should be like `<input type="button" id="myDiv" value="Add Custom Slug" name="answer" onclick="ShowDiv()" /> `. If you want to hide that button.

Comment: see the demo i updated my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a Checkbox instead... like..

```
<div id="custom_url" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="custom_url" value="<?php echo htmlentities(@$_GET['custom_url'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>" id="custom_url" placeholder="Custom Slug" /> 
    <label for="custom_url">Optional</label> 
</div>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('custom_url', this)">Custom URL

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function showMe (it, box) {
  var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;
}
//-->
</script>
```

Do this..

Answer (score 2):

You can set a id for the button and hide it when the ShowDiv function executes:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >
    <input type="text" name="custom_url" value="<?php echo htmlentities(@$_GET['custom_url'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>" id="custom_url" placeholder="Custom Slug" /> 
    <label for="custom_url">Optional</label> 
</div>
<div>
    <input id="add-cutom-slug-btn" type="button" value="Add Custom Slug" name="answer" onclick="ShowDiv()" />
</div>

<script>
function ShowDiv() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("add-cutom-slug-btn").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks... Yes Sure... But I need to earn 15 rep to do that :p

Comment: That\'s for vote up, just click below the down arrow, left side of the answer on the grey check mark.

Comment: Can you just implement a code, replace Button with a Check Box

Comment: You will have to write another question with more information about what you are going to do, what's have you tried and the intended behavior you want.

Answer (score -1):

jquery way

Use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

```
$('#myDiv').hide();
```

> Description: Hide the matched elements.

to show

Use [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

```
$('#myDiv').show();
```

> Description: Display the matched elements.

```js
$('#hide').click(function() {
  $('#myDiv').hide();
})
$('#show').click(function() {
  $('#myDiv').show();
})
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('#myDiv').toggle('slow');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" class="answer_list">
  <input type="text" name="custom_url" value="qwe" id="custom_url" placeholder="Custom Slug" />
  <label for="custom_url">Optional</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="hide" id="hide" name="answer" />
  <input type="button" value="show" id="show" name="answer" />
  <input type="button" value="toggle" id="toggle" name="answer" />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know how and where to put these jquery codes.. Please help me with that too...

Comment: @NitinJain yes the link is for?

Comment: i see so it worked now?glad it worked now. happy coding mate